# Template class with operator overload

Tags: c++, class, templates, operator-overloading

Here is my question about template class

```
aclass<int> A{1,2};
aclass<float> B{3.0,4.0};
aclass<int> C;

int main()
{
  C=A+B;   //How to overload this operator in a simple way?
  B=A;   //And also this?
  return 0;
}
```

How can I overload operator to handle template class with different types?
(Sorry for my poor English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have member function templates inside your class template:

```
template <typename T>
struct aclass
{
    aclass(aclass const &) = default;
    aclass & operator=(const aclass &) = default;

    template <typename U>
    aclass(aclass<U> const & rhs) : a_(rhs.a_), b_(rhs.b_) {}

    template <typename U>
    aclass & operator=(aclass<U> const & rhs)
    {
        a_ = rhs.a_;
        b_ = rhs.b_;
        return *this;
    }

    T a_, b_;
};
```

Comment: How can I make operator= as a friend function?

Comment: @charliepu123: You can make all template instances a friend: `template <typename> friend struct aclass;`